# Android OpenSL example does not load libOpenSLES.so?

Tags: audio, android-ndk, opensl

I succesfully built an Android NDK application that uses the OpenSL library in Android with the help of this tutorial
http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/

In opensl_io.h the following is stated:

```
#include <SLES/OpenSLES.h>
#include <SLES/OpenSLES_Android.h>
```

I was wondering whether this has the effect that on my device the library in `/system/lib/libOpenSLES.so` is loaded.

I thought that the library has to be loaded at some point because in the Android.mk it is stated

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lOpenSLES
```

and the [ndk doc](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/STABLE-APIS.html) tells me that this means that `/system/lib/libOpenSLES.so` and not any other is used for `-lOpenSLES`

So I wrote an app with superuser rights that has a FileWatcher on that file.

However it seems that the library is never touched, when I use my OpenSL example.

For other libraries such as `/system/lib/libstdc++.so`, I can see with a FileWatcher that they are loaded.

So my questions is: Why is `/system/lib/libOpenSLES.so` not used?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to add `-lOpenSLES` and the `#include` directives to to make your code actually link to **libOpenSLES.so**. It would be enough if you place a call to one single function from that library, even in such call will never be executed (be careful not to put it in a block that an optimizing compiler will completely discard).

Answer (score 0):

What is the errors you are getting?. I had a problem with calling these libraries when i was creating an audio app. The problem was that in my java wrapper file i was not loading the libraries. The following code should be used to load the libraries into the java class

```
static{
        System.loadLibrary("com_example_packageName");
    }
```

packageName should be your app package name.

Comment: thanks for the response. However my java code does have this code already

Comment: No problem, also noticed that the sample apps in the ndk using OpenSL ES have a slightly different value in their Android.mk file. They use

    LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lOpenSLES